# Как сделать без пустых дивов?

Tags: html, css

сейчас выглядит довольно странно

http://codepen.io/Olya097/pen/xxjrvRb

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

.block {
  width: calc(20% - 10px);
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #faf;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  
  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
  
    <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
  
      <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: скорее всего никак через css, вы хотя бы класс пустым дивам задавайте и скрывайте

Comment: могу ошибаться но вероятно вы заполняете эти дивы не вручную, а генерируете на странице, если так то я бы предложил бы поработать с данными а не с css так как это так или иначе затрагивает DOM дерево

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно исключить отображение **полностью** пустых блоков, то используйте псевдокласс [:empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) :

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

.block {
  width: calc(20% - 10px);
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #faf;
}
.block:empty { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block">content</div>

  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block">content</div>

  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Если же нужно блоки скрыть, не удаляя из разметки и не ломая поток, то можно использовать `visibility: hidden` вместо `display: none` :

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

.block {
  width: calc(20% - 10px);
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #faf;
}
.block:empty { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block">content</div>

  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block">content</div>

  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

В перспективе ожидается поддержка псевдокласса [:blank](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-only-whitespace), который считает пустыми даже те блоки, где только пробельные символы.

Answer (score 0):

В css есть псевдокласс :empty. Просто используйте его!

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

.block {
  width: calc(20% - 10px);
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #faf;
}

.block:empty {
  display: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  
  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
  
    <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
  
      <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block">content</div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```